# Existence of a solution to $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, b\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that $Ax=b$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff all solutions $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ of $A^Ty=0$ satisfy $(y,b)=0$.

Showing that if there exists an $x$, then all the solutions $y$ satisfy $(y,b)=0$ is straight forward, but I am stuck on the other direction. I do not really know how I should show existence, as I am not sure what such an $x$ should look like. And I am also not sure how assuming there does not exist an $x$ would help me. So any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint $\langle Ax,y \rangle=\langle x,A^Ty \rangle=\langle x,0 \rangle=0$ and use definition of inner product spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done assuming we use some facts about the orthogonal complement:

Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$; define $W^\perp = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n : (v,w) = 0 \text{ for all }w \in W\}$.  The fact we'll want to use is that $(W^\perp)^\perp = W$.

Here's the idea then: let $C(A)$ denote the column space of $A$; then by definition, $C(A) = \{b : Ax = b \text{ has a solution}\}$.  Similarly, define $N(A^T)$ to be the left-nullspace of $A$.  A key point in linear algebra is that $N(A^T) = C(A)^\perp$.  There's nothing heavy in that statement, it follows directly from the definition of the orthogonal complement.

Now, you are essentially trying to show that if $b$ is orthogonal to each $y \in N(A^T)$ then $b \in C(A)$.  But this first condition is precisely that $b \in N(A^T)^\perp$, which is equal to $(C(A)^\perp)^\perp = C(A).$